# Remove URL from extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, omnibox

I built a new chrome extension and want to remove\hide the URL (chrome-extension://id/).

Any idea how to remove it? 
I already tried to do that with [History.API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and [chrome.omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox)

Comment: Not possible. The only workaround is to set your extension page as a [new tab replacement](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).

Comment: I will look into this option. Thank you

Comment: It's only work on the first page, my extension builds from 2 html files

Comment: Maybe you can switch to [SPA library/framework](https://www.google.com/#q=SPA%20libraries%2Fframeworks%20and%20tutorials).